# Debian wheezy Xorg configuration fails, Debian don't boot

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, debian-wheezy

I have installed Debian Wheezy today.

when i boot Debian wheezy when splash logo about to open, the screen blanks and system hangs, but Debian stable was booted without errors, but

I changed init parameter to `init=/bin/sh`,
Then `mount -o remount,rw /`

its all ok, but when i try to start x server with this command:

```
Xorg
```

The screen is blank and system locked.

There isn't a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe`

What i tried so far:

copied https://launchpadlibrarian.net/21150771/xorg.conf.failsafe
 to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, when i start Xorg it says no screens found, when i reboot without touching init= command, the screen is still hang and blank at bootup logo.

Tried Xorg -configure, generated xorg.conf but not worked.

What i can do? P.S. i have readon 2600 HD pro

Answer (score 1):

Please post the output of the following command:

```
grep -A3 -B3 "(EE)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

That's a way to get the lines containing (EE), which are important as they indicate errors. The command will also include 3 lines before and after each error, just to get a little bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

`xorgsetup` # menu wizard for easy xorg config

`startx` # start X

`dmesg | tail -n 30` # if start x fail, show dmesg

`grep \(EE\) /var/log/Xorg.0.log` # xorg log, errors should be here

Comment: Getting xorgsetup and Xorgsetup not found error

Comment: from google: `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` or `X
-configure` instead of `xorgsetup`. I am not familiar with Debian.